# Postman BDD testing array of object REST API

Tags: javascript, postman, chai

I'm writing tests using Postman BDD / Chai and have ran in to an issue testing a response that is an array.

So my API returns something along the lines of

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "x",
            "lastName": "y",
            "dateOfBirth": "2018-04-21",
            "username": "user"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "x",
            "lastName": "y",
            "dateOfBirth": "2018-04-21",
            "username": "admin"
        } 
]
```

How do I check that the response contains certain members?

```
expect(response).to.have.property('id');
```

Does not seem to function since the response is an array. Changing response to response[0] doesn't seem to change anything either.

Suggestions?

Comment: you just want to make sure that all of your response objects have `id` ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey No, I want to check more members but that was just an example. Main question is how to access the objects within the array.

Comment: loop through it. `.map` etc

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Would this be supported by Postman BDD?

Comment: You’ll need to loop through the data to assert that the different properties are in the array. Is there a reason you’re using Postman BDD over the newer builtin tests feature with all the `pm.*` functions?

Answer (score 2):

You could just add something like this into the `Tests` tab without the need to use the Postman BDD library. I've used Lodash here but you could do the same thing with native JS using a `for loop`:

```
pm.test('Response has the ID property', () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json(), (arrItem) => {
        console.log(arrItem)
        pm.expect(arrItem).to.have.property('id')
    })
})
```

[image]

You could extend this to check the whole object for specfic elements - Add another line in the test like `pm.expect(arrItem).to.have.property('firstName')` for example.

If you are using the [PostmanBDD](https://github.com/BigstickCarpet/postman-bdd) library you can add a `for` loop to check for the `id` property:

```
eval(globals.postmanBDD)

describe('Get id data', () => {
  it('should check the id property is present', () => {
      for(i=0; i < response.body.length; i++) {
          console.log(response.body[i])
          response.body[i].should.have.property('id')
      }
  })
})
```

[image: Postman]